# Wordpress apache2 virtual host configuration on a debian install

Tags: wordpress, apache, debian, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm trying to setup a wordpress site on my server that also hosts another website. I can only get the wordpress site to work with the web address `blog.murmilosoftware.com/wp`.

I want to be able to simply access it from `blog.murmilosoftware.com`.

The problem is when I type `blog.murmilosoftware.com` in right now it displays the same page that is available from `murmilosoftware.com`.

I have attached both of the sites-available config files from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

**blog.murmillosoftware.com.conf**

```
Alias /wp/wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
Alias /wp /usr/share/wordpress
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**murmillosoftware.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin erik@murmillosoftware.com
    ServerName murmillosoftware.com
    ServerAlias www.murmillosoftware.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> Forgot to restart my apache service. It is working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you notice the `<VirtualHost *:80>` in your `murmillosoftware.com.conf` file? That is called the Virtual Host configuration. In your current `blog.murmillosoftware.com.conf`, all you're doing is creating an alias to `/wp` path, which is why you're able to browse wordpress there.

Update your `blog.murmillosoftware.com.conf` as follows (might be buggy, keep checking server logs):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin erik@murmillosoftware.com
    ServerName blog.murmillosoftware.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress

    # Custom log files, to differentiate from root server
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-wordpress.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-wordpress.log combined

    Alias /wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
    <Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what is `AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo` for?  should this not be `AllowOverride ALL`